# Is it possible to tell the compiler (msvc, gcc) to leave a particular register alone?

Tags: visual-c++, gcc, calling-convention

Is it possible to modify the calling conventions of the compiler such that the generated code refrains from using a particular CPU register? I'd be interested in solutions for recent versions of gcc and msvc.

Update: -ffixed-reg and/or Explicit-Reg-Vars seem to do the trick for gcc. Thank you for your answers. Is there a similar mechanism for MSVC?

Comment: maybe try `-ffixed-reg` see gcc docs for details ...

Answer (score 3):

As per the [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#Code-Gen-Options):

> ffixed-reg
>
> Treat the register named reg as a fixed register; generated code should never refer to it (except perhaps as a stack pointer, frame pointer  or in some other fixed role).
>
> reg must be the name of a register. The register names accepted are machine-specific and are defined in the REGISTER_NAMES macro in the     machine description macro file.
>
> This flag does not have a negative form, because it specifies a three-way choice.